# How to drill hole in joist for ethernet

Tags: wiring, wood, drill, joists

i have a bit of an issue. I live in a 2 story house and I'd like to run 2 ethernet cables down to the first floor from my room. The issue is that when I drilled the hole, i drilled it diagonally through the joist and it eventually punctured my family room wall. Would it be alright to drill a hole in the joist from the bottom hole that would eventually meet the puncture hole halfway and create an opening for the cables? [image: you can see the size of the joist from this angle] Or would that destroy the structural integrity of the joist? [image: this is the joist and drywall from a sideview. The red is the wood joist. The purple is the diagonal puncture I foolishly made. And the blue is the hole I'm thinking about making. But I need advice on if it's the best option.] The drawing depicts a side view of the joist and drywall. The red is the wood joist. The purple is the diagonal puncture I foolishly made. And the blue is the hole I'm thinking about making. But I need advice on if it's the best option. I don't want my room crumbling..

Comment: Since you've already made cuts in the drywall, why not route the ethernet cable *over* the front of the joist instead of through it? You'd need to make a channel between your two square holes, but you're going to need to patch things anyway, so what's a little extra?

Comment: @CactusCake I might actually just do that rather than making another hole at the bottom. I'll make a groove near the front of the joist to slip wires through.

Comment: Legally speaking, (and at least where I'm from) no holes or channels are permitted in the lower 2/3 of a horizontal supporting member. Essentially a hole at 2 inches from the bottom would turn a 10in joist into an 8in joist, and thus not meet the structural requirements.